# For which $n$ does there exist a closed manifold of (chromatic) type $n$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, chromatic-homotopy

Let $p$ be a prime and $n \in \mathbb N$. Does there exist a closed manifold which is of type $n$ after $p$-localization?

When $n= 0$ the answer is yes. When $p = 2$ and $n = 1$ we can take $\mathbb R \mathbb P ^2$.

Other than that, I'm not sure.

**Notes:**

- Recall that a finite CW complex $X$ is said to be of type $n$ if $\widetilde{K(n)}_\ast X \neq 0$ but $\widetilde{K(m)}_\ast X = 0$ for $m < n$, where $K(n)$ is the $n$th Morava $K$-theory at the prime $p$.
- Recall the [thick subcategory theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thick+subcategory+theorem) tells us that for every $n$ (and every $p$) there exists a finite CW complex which is of type $n$ after $p$-localization, and conversely that every finite CW complex is of type $n$ for some $n$ after $p$-localization. The question is whether "finite CW complex" can be upgraded to "closed manifold".
- When $n \geq 1$, a closed manifold of type $n$ can't be orientable (since if it's orientable, then by Poincare duality its reduced rational homology is nonvanishing, and $K(0) = H\mathbb Q$).

Comment: The question of $n>1$ at odd primes remains open, doesn't it? At the other question, you assert that Saal ruled it out, but I don't see it. https://mathoverflow.net/q/410802/4639

Comment: @BenWieland Oh wow you're right -- what I had in my head was the fact that $KO_\ast M \neq 0 \Rightarrow KU_\ast M \neq 0$, but this doesn't imply that $KU_\ast M_{(p)} \neq 0$...

Comment: @BenWieland In fact, I don't think we've even established that there _do_ exist closed manifolds $M$ such that $M_{(p)}$ is of type 1 when $p$ is odd -- only that there exist such of type $>0$!

Comment: Although (and I could be wrong about this) -- if $p$ is odd and $M$ is a closed 4-manifold such that $M_{(p)}$ is of type $>0$, then I believe that the AHSS for $KO_{(p)}^\ast(\Sigma M_{(p)})$ collapses, so that $\widetilde{KO}^\ast(M_{(p)}) \neq 0$, so that $\widetilde{KU}^\ast(M_{(p)})\neq 0$, so that $M_{(p)}$ is of type 1. So the question, as you said, is whether $M$ can be chosen such that $M_{(p)}$ has type $\geq 2$...

Comment: (1) A really degenerate example is $\mathbb RP^2$ at an odd prime. It has type $\geqslant 2$, which means that to rule out the existence of type 2 requires actually using the existence of $p$-torsion. (2) I'm pretty sure the lens space example has type 1: Lens spaces themselves have $p$-torsion in $K$-theory; indeed, the $p$-torsion in homology assembles into $p^n$-torsion in $K$. (3) I think that in studying surgery theory, Sullivan proved that every oriented manifold is $L$-oriented and $L[1/2]=KO[1/2]$. I suspect one can use this to rule out high type for unorientable manifolds.

Comment: For an odd prime, take a type $n$ complex, embed it in Euclidean space and take a regular neighborhood. This is is a parallelized manifold with boundary with the homotopy type of the original complex. Its boundary is the dual of the original complex, still type $n$, but with a top cell that splits off. Double it on its boundary to get a space which the sum of the original complex, its dual, a zero-sphere, and a big sphere. Take the connected sum with $\mathbb RP^2$ to kill off the top cell. I think this should do it. (My comment (3) was silly, exactly the kind of thing my (1) was aimed at.)

Comment: @BenWieland That construction sounds like it would make a great answer! I get a little lost, and could use some more details. For a start, the boundary of the regular neighborhood sounds related to, but not exactly the same as, the complement of the complex in a big sphere (a model of the SW dual which I'm more comfortable with). I'm not sure what it means to double this manifold, and from there I get even more lost.

Comment: The double of a manifold with boundary is the manifold without boundary produced by gluing two copies of the manifold along the boundary. Yes, I made some mistakes. The boundary is something like the sum of the complex and its dual. Then the double is sum of the complex and its dual shifted up another degree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After discussing this with Tim we came up with the following answer:

The first steifel whiteny class $\omega_1$ of $M$ can be written as the following composition:

$$M \to BO(n) \to BO \to BAut(\mathbb{S}) \to BAut(\mathbb{Z}) \simeq B\mathbb{Z}/2$$

But if $M$ is of type $\ge 2$ then $[M,BO]\simeq [\Sigma^\infty M, bo] \simeq 0$ since $bo$ is of height $\le 1$. So $M$ must be orientable in cotradiction with the third point.

**Conclusion:** All closed smooth manifolds are of type $\le 1$.

<s>Oh and I believe that at odd primes, type $1$ complexes can be realized by Lens manifolds.</s> Here I was uncareful. This is wrong as it conflicts with the Tim's third point as was pointed out by Gregory Arone in the comments.

Comment: Lens manifolds are orientable though. So this belief seems to clash with one of Tim's observations.

Comment: Otherwise said, if $M$ is not oriented then $M$ has a nontrivial element in $KO$-theory, and so in $K(1)$.  Oh gosh, this was simple.

Comment: @GregoryArone Thanks for catching that. I should be more careful with my beliefs in the future.

Comment: Turns out the answer for $n=1$ and $p$ odd [is also yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410802/does-there-exist-a-closed-manifold-with-vanishing-reduced-rational-cohomology-bu?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @TimCampion Actually, i was meaning to edit my answer. The other primes are kind of a red hearing. You must have 2 torsion to be non-orientable. On the other hand you can always take a product of a Lens manifold with RP^2 and that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @SaalHardali Your last comment is off: the product of a projective plane and lens space will still have nonzero rational homology (just not in the top dimension).  But Tim's comments points to the answer: one needs a little bit more, but not too more, cleverness to do this.

Comment: @NicholasKuhn Oh i see that now. Sorry, yes i agree.

Comment: @SaalHardali Sorry to unaccept, but as Ben Wieland reminded me in the comments [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410577/for-which-n-does-there-exist-a-closed-manifold-of-chromatic-type-n?noredirect=1#comment1055484_410577), at odd primes, I'm wondering what the type of $M_{(p)}$ can be, so I don't think the answer is settled at odd primes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of the situation at odd primes, following [Ben Wieland's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410577/for-which-n-does-there-exist-a-closed-manifold-of-chromatic-type-n#comment1056278_410577). In all the following, fix an odd prime $p$.

First, note that as in [Saal's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/410684/2362), every closed manifold $M$ with vanishing rational homology is nonorientable, and thus admits a nonvanishing 2-torsion class in $\widetilde{KO}^0(M)$, and thus $\widetilde{KU^\wedge_2}^\ast(M) \neq 0$. Thus $M$ is not literally $p$-local. The remaining question is what the type of the $p$-localization $M_{(p)}$ can be. Ben's comment shows that the type of $M_{(p)}$ can be arbitrary. Let me attempt to expand out Ben's construction.

- Let $X$ be a finite complex such that $X_{(p)}$ is a type $n$ spectrum.

Embed $X$ in a big sphere $S^N$, and

- Let $M$ be the boundary of a regular neighborhood of $X$.

Then $M$ is a closed manifold of dimension $N-1$. Assume that $N = 2d+1$ is odd, and

- Let $M' = M \# \mathbb R\mathbb P^{N-1} = M \# \mathbb R\mathbb P^{2d}$ be the connected sum of $M$ with real projective space.

**Claim:** $M'_{(p)}$ is of type $n$.

**Analysis of $\mathbb R\mathbb P^{2d}$:**

Observe that $\widetilde{H}_\ast(\mathbb R \mathbb P^{2d};\mathbb Z_{(p)}) = 0$, so that $\mathbb R \mathbb P^{2d}_{(p)} = 0$. It follows that the attaching map for the top cell $S^{2d-1} \to \mathbb R\mathbb P^{2d} \setminus \ast$ induces an isomorphism in $K(m)_\ast$ for all $m$.

**Analysis of $M$:**

We have a homotopy pushout

$$(\ast) \quad S^N \simeq X \cup_M \Sigma^N (DX)$$

(Here $DX$ is the Spanier-Whitehead dual of $X$; $\Sigma^N DX$ is modeled by the complement of $X$ in $S^N$; note that $DX_{(p)}$, like $X$ has type $n$.)

The Mayer-Vietoris square for $(\ast)$ shows that for $m < n$, we have $K(m) \wedge M = \Sigma^{N-1} K(m)$ . For $m \geq n$, since $K(m)_\ast S^N$ is 2-dimensional over $K(m)_\ast$ and $K(m)_\ast (X \amalg DX)$ is at least 4-dimensional; it follows that $\widetilde{K(m)}_\ast M \neq 0$ for $m \geq n$. Thus for all $m$, we have $\widetilde{K(m)}_\ast M = \Sigma^{N-1} K(m)_\ast \oplus L(m)$, where $L(m) = 0$ iff $m < n$.

Into $(\ast)$, we may include a homotopy pushout diagram $(S^N\setminus \ast) \simeq (X \setminus \ast) \cup_{M \setminus \ast} ((\Sigma^N (DX)) \setminus \ast)$. The cofiber is a homotopy pushout diagram $S^N = \ast \cup_{S^{N-1}} \ast$. From this, we may conclude that the map $M \to S^{N-1}$ collapsing all but the top cell  (which is the double cofiber of the attaching map $S^{N-2} \to M \setminus \ast$) kills exactly $L(m)$ in $\widetilde{K(m)_\ast}$, leaving $\widetilde{K(m)}_\ast (M \setminus \ast) = L(m)$.

**Analysis of the connected sum:**

Now from the homotopy pushout $M' \simeq (M \setminus \ast) \cup_{S^{N-2}} (\mathbb R \mathbb P^{N-1} \setminus \ast)$, we conclude that $\widetilde{K(m)}_\ast (M') = L(m)$, which vanishes exactly when $m < n$. Thus $M'_{(p)}$ has type $n$.