# Does there exist a closed manifold with vanishing reduced rational cohomology but nonvanishing odd torsion cohomology?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

**Question:** Let $p$ be an odd prime. Does there exist a closed manifold $M$ with $\widetilde H^\ast(M; \mathbb Q) = 0$ but $\widetilde H^\ast(M; \mathbb F_p) \neq 0$?

When $p = 2$, an example is given by $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$.

<strike>After discussion, this question turns out to be equivalent to [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410577/for-which-n-does-there-exist-a-closed-manifold-of-chromatic-type-n). That is, over at that question Saal Hardali explained that if $M$ is a closed manifold, then the chromatic type of $M$ at a prime $p$ is either 0 or 1. Both possibilities are realized at $p=2$; the question is whether chromatic type 1 is realized at odd primes. Chromatic type 0 just means having nonvanishing rational (co)homology. So the question is whether there exists a closed manifold $M$ which is rationally contractible but whose $p$-localization is nontrivial for an odd $p$.</strike>  This turned out to be mistaken, thanks to Ben Wieland for pointing this out at the other question.

**Side Question:** When $p=2$, what are some other examples of $M$ with $\widetilde H^\ast(M;\mathbb Q) = 0$ but $\widetilde H^\ast(M;\mathbb F_2) \neq 0$ besides $M = \mathbb R \mathbb P^{2n}$ and products thereof?

Comment: @mme Are lens spaces manifolds?

Comment: Yes, they're quotients of a manifold by a free finite group actions.

Comment: They are manifolds, but rationally  are not a point (they are orientable)

Comment: Oh, I misread. So sorry. Deleted my silly comment. I somehow thought you were looking for rational homology spheres.

Comment: What if you start with a non-orientable three fold, and apply surgery to it?

Comment: Another thing, which I was trying to do, is to take a lens space like L(6,1) and study the non-orientable circle bundle over it

Comment: @ThomasRot Non-orientable odd-dimensional closed manifolds cannot be rational homology balls, because every odd-dimensional closed manifold has zero Euler characteristic (use Poincare duality on the oriented double cover.) So your second approach sounds more promising.

Comment: @mme: Nice observatino. So, so far we know it must be even-dimensional and non-orientable.

Comment: @mme: I now believe that the circle bundle over lens spaces is not going to work. The fundamental group of the circle bundle contains a $Z$ summand (generated by a loop in the fiber), which can be seen from the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of the fiber bundle

Comment: @TimCampion: I don't understand that comment. What about n=1. The double cover of RP^2 is S^2

Comment: @ThomasRot Sorry -- I just don't know what I'm talking about! (I messed up computing the Euler characteristic of an even-dimensional manifold)

Comment: @TimCampion: No worries, maybe I am misunderstanding something!

Comment: What if you take $\mathbb{RP}^{2n} \# M$, where $M$ is an (orientable) rational homology sphere?

Comment: @ThomasRot: regarding your circle bundle idea, the $\mathbb{Z}$ "summand" coming from the circle isn't always visible in $H_1$. For an example one dimension down, take $U$ to be the unit tangent bundle of a hyperbolic surface $S$. There is a short exact sequence $1\to\mathbb{Z}\to\pi_1(U)\to\pi_1(S)\to 1$, but it doesn't split, and in fact $H_1(U)\cong H_1(S)$.

Comment: @TimCampion: Marco Golla's xample is an answer to the main question I think.

Comment: Ah ok -- @MarcoGolla, I don't understand -- could you explain? I don't see why $\mathbb R \mathbb P^{2n} \# M$ is is rationally trivial nor why it is $p$-locally nontrivial.

Comment: I'll try to write up an answer later, but it boils down to Mayer–Vietoris: connected summing with a rational homology sphere doesn't do anything to the rational homology, but it keeps all the p-torsion if there was any to begin with.

Comment: Maybe I should also say that this is essentially a version of what Thomas Rot was suggesting when he said "let's do surgery".

Comment: A circle bundle over an odd dimensional manifold has Euler characteristic zero, because Euler characteristic is multiplicative. Either the base or fiber being zero suffices, but this has both.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As mme noted in the comments, such examples cannot exist in odd dimensions, for Euler characteristic reasons. They can't exist in dimension 2 either, by classification. I claim that in all other dimensions $2n > 2$ we have (plenty of) examples.

Let $N$ be a rational homology $2n$-sphere, that is a $2n$-manifold with $H_*(N; \mathbb{Q}) = H_*(S^{2n}; \mathbb{Q})$. For every prime $p$ there exists a rational homology $2n$-sphere with $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} H_*(N;\mathbb{F}_p) > 2$. For instance, you can take a spun lens space (any spun rational homology $2n-1$-sphere would do).

Now, the integral homology of $M = \mathbb{RP}^{2n} \# N$ splits as a direct sum of that of the two summands in all dimensions strictly between 0 and 2n, and it vanishes in dimension 2n (because $M$ is non-orientable) and it is $\mathbb{Z}$ in dimension 0 (because $M$ is connected). (This is Exercise 6 in Section 3.3 of Hatcher's *Algebraic topology*.) That is, $M$ is a rational homology ball, and its homology has as much $p$-torsion as that of $N$.

For the side question, if we choose $N$ to have no 2-torsion in its homology (e.g. spinning an odd lens space should do the trick), this gives plenty of examples.

Comment: In case it is helpful for Tim, let me remind the definition of "spinning an n-manifold": if $M$ is closed of dimension $n$, puncture it by deleting the interior of a fixed embedding of the smooth n-ball: this is a compact manifold $P(M) = M \setminus D^n$ with parameterized boundary $S^{n-1}$ . Now consider $P(M) \times S^1$, which has boundary equipped with a diffeomorphism to $S^{n-1} \times S^1$. Fill in this boundary by gluing in $S^{n-1} \times D^2$. Said another way, take $M \times S^1$ and do surgery along $p \times S^1$. The homology is obtained by a Mayer-Vietoris computation.

Comment: Try picturing this for M = S^1 and you'll see that this gives the picture of the 2-sphere by taking an arc from north pole to south pole and spinning it 360 degrees.

Comment: Thanks! I must admit I am currently remedially reminding myself what the homology of a nonorientable manifold looks like!